# how to subset a matrix randomly from a large matrix in Julia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I have a large matrix(28960×45807 Array{Float64,2}), where rows represent individuals and columns for snpID. now I want to get a subset matrix(28960x4580) that snps are selected ramdomly from large matrix.
how can I do it in Julia?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your matrix is `x`:

```
using StatsBase
@view x[:, sample(1:size(x,2), 4580, replace=false, ordered=true)]
```

Exaplanation:

- Using `@view` avoids data copying. It could be skipped in this command but it would worsen the performance
- The colon `:` selects the data across all rows, the second parameter of array slicing is used to select a bunch of columns
- `size(x,2)` returns the number of columns
- we use `sample` from `StatsBase` to sample the column numbers without replacement. Additionally, I assumed that you do not want to change the order of columns

Comment: could you explain the command little bit ? and why you did not used (Rand) ?

Comment: there you go - here it is

Comment: thank you sir, really appreciate your help

Comment: Maybe `axes(x, 2)` instead of `1:size(x, 2)`?

Comment: @DNF agree looks slightly better :-)